# Installing scanner

Tags: scanner

I am trying to install a new scanner (a Canon Canoscan 9000F Mark II, which is fully supported by SANE, according to the list of SANE-supported scanners.  I have downloaded and compiled the current set of SANE back-ends, following the instructions in 
[this scanner blog.](http://mp610.blogspot.ca/2008_04_01_archive.html)  I have created scanner devices (in /dev), following the instructions in 
[this guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Scanner-HOWTO/dev-intro.html), including use of the "scanner" group.

I am receiving a reasonable-looking response from the scanner when I execute "sane-find-scanner".  However, "scanimage -L" responds "no scanners were identified", and "scanimage -T" responds "no SANE devices found".

Any suggestions as to what I've done wrong, or failed to do?  (Running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: You should not have compiled SANE from source, but used Ubuntu packages.